# Condition checking in active admin table_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have 2 tables preorder and payment with has_many relation, I want display the contents in table only after checking the status (boolean) condition, I tried with following code snippet but its not working? How to do check the condition inside the table_for?

```
  panel "payment" do
    table_for preorder.payments do |a|
      if a.status.nil?
        column "Received On",     :created_at
        column "Details & Notes", :payment_details
        column "Amount",          :amount_in_dollars
      end
    end
  end
```

**Payment model**
attr_accessible :created_at, :payment_details, :status, :amount_in_dollars
belongs_to :preorder

**preorder model**
attr_accessible :name, :order
has_many :payments

I want to display the payment details in preorder admin page based on status.

Comment: Use `if a.status` instead of `if a.status.nil?`.

Comment: Its throwing error as undefined method 'status'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code. I hope it works.

```
panel "payment" do
 table_for preorder.payments do |a|
   unless a.blank?
    if a.status
      column "Received On",     :created_at
      column "Details & Notes", :payment_details
      column "Amount",          :amount_in_dollars
    end
   end
 end
end
```

Comment: Just for a test purpose could you please run Preorder.first.payments.last.status in your rails console and see if you are getting any result.

Comment: My guess is that you have not added the column status to your payments table. Kindly check your schema.rb file for payments table once.

Comment: console showing error as undefined method 'Payments'

Comment: It should be Preorder.first.payments.last.status not Preorder.first.Payments.last.status